# Java don't update variable after run first time

Tags: java

Sorry about to ask for it, but I'm really noob at Java. When we call for showWindow...

```
public static String checkList;

public static String getCheckList(){
    return checkList;
}

public static void setCheckList(String queryToSelect){
    checkList = queryToSelect;
}

public static void showWindow(User user)
{
    if (!checkConditions(user))
        return;

    String msg;
    String queryToSelectshow;

    if (user.getNetConnection().getBonus() > 0.)
    {
        msg = main(user);
        queryToSelectshow = "SELECT * FROM prodlist WHERE canUse = 1 ORDER BY description ASC, id";
    }
    else
    {
        msg = main(user);
        queryToSelectshow = "SELECT * FROM prodlist WHERE canUse = 2 ORDER BY description ASC, id";
    }
    setCheckList(queryToSelectshow);
    showCommunity(user, msg);
}
```

If user has bonus then queryToSelectshow 1 else queryToSelectshow 2, but If I run this with user with bonus this set queryToSelectshow 1 and when I run with user with no bunus this still in queryToSelectshow 1 and need to be queryToSelectshow 2.

Is this caused by the "static" function? I tried to do without Static, but when I try to do It the eclipse shows me a lot of error messages!

Thank you for help and your time!

Comment: can you show code,how do you connect to database and execute that query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... there is a lot of code that we can't see, but I would recommend you to log the value from "user.getNetConnection().getBonus()" before getting in the if. Or if you don't have any loging system, just show it with `System.out.println(user.getNetConnection().getBonus())`
In that way, you can get sure from that the value that you are getting is really going to be more than 0.
Also, if you are using an IDE, learn to debug your code. Making a quick search, for Eclipse for example:
[Debug Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Also... are you really needing all those methods to be static? I will suppose that you are doing it because, if not, you can't call them from the main method. In that case, you can create a new object from the same class:

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
```

and then call the non static methods:

```
object.nonStaticMethod();
```

I would recommend you to try to understand what does it mean for a method to be static (and for variables also!!!) :
[Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, I'm newbie in Java and that System.out... help-me to debug. I put the System.out... in the finish of function showWindow and  as I see, when I use showWindow with bonus user, it shows the value 2.5 and when I use non bonus user, it shows 0.0. It shows correct, but the query still getting the same value. The problem is because I'm using Static methods and when this get a value, can't change anymore. I'll try to follow your instructions to do non static. Lol, that's really hard to understand (how to do it), but I'll try. Thank you at all!

Comment: :D After a while it will come naturally. Also try to learn how to debug. It will REALLY help you to find out the values from everything at any point. It is not so complicated as it seems. Don't give up on it! :)

Comment: Yes!!! Only with the debug, I'm able to fix it. Thank you very much! You are the master!

Comment: Ou you... :D Don't forget to give it a look to the link about static members. If you are going to keep on programming in Java, it is going to help you to understand a lot of code that you are going to face. Now go and keep on learning, my little padawan!